# I have never used JOIN. When is proper time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, join

I have never used `JOIN(INNER, OUTER)`, and I don't have any idea when is the best scenario:

Here I have two examples of `ActionResults` that uses 2 or 3 queries to get an object, isn't better to use a `JOIN` instead?

First Example:

```
public ActionResult JobTags(int id)
{
   var jobTagsList = (from j in db.JobTags
                           where j.JobID == id
                           select j.TagID).ToList();

   var tags = (from j in db.Tags
                    where jobTagsList.Contains(j.ID.ToString())
                    select j).ToList();

   return View(tags);
}
```

Can I just `JOIN` this two tables and select that j at the end?

Second Example:

```
public ActionResult ImageListWhoApp(int id)
{
    //We get here the ID from Job page using dbo.Jobs
    var userIdList = (from j in db.Jobs
                           where j.ID == id
                           select j.ID.ToString()).ToList();

    //We get here who applied at this job using dbo.AppliedJobs
    var appJobIdList = (from j in db.AppliedJobs
                    where userIdList.Contains(j.JobID.ToString())
                    select j.UserID).ToList();

    //Finally we get here the avatars of the user who applied at the job
    //We are using this as a hyperlink to user profile.
    var appUserImage = (from j in db.Images
                            where appJobIdList.Contains(j.UserID.ToString())
                            select j).ToList();

    return View(appUserImage);
}
```

Isn't this approach getting ridiculous? Or is normal to do stuff like this in this manner? How do I make a `JOIN` from this 3 `SQL` statements? Is it possible? is it the better way?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Don't you have Navigation properties in your Model classes? They are what make Joins mostly unnecessary.

Comment: me too, because `JOIN` in LINQ is verbose and limited compared to `JOIN` in T-SQL.

Comment: If you use EF and have navigation properties, then a `JOIN` is normally not needed. But if you have two list with objects which you want to combine, then it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @qxg: Verbosity is highly opinion based and for the limits of `.Join()` in LINQ you should take a look at `.GroupJoin()`.

Comment: yea I completely forgot about navigation properties, and in this case I don't need `JOIN` anyway, it was just questioning myself why I didn't used `JOIN` at all by now. But makes sense about returning two lists at once, I never needed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need joins. You can use navigation properties:

```
var tagsQry =
    from tag in db.Tags
    where tag.JobTag.JobID == id
    select tag;

var userImageQry =
    from img in db.Images
    from appJob in db.AppliedJobs
    where (img.UserID == appJob.UserID) && (appJob.Job.ID == id)
    select img;
```

Even if you have no navigation properties, you don't need joins:

```
var tagsQry =
    from tag in db.Tags
    from jobTag in sb.JobTags
    where (jobTag.JobID == id) && (tag.ID == jobTag.TagID)
    select tag;

var userImageQry =
    from img in db.Images
    from appJob in db.AppliedJobs
    from job in db.Jobs
    where (img.UserID == appJob.UserID) && (appJob.JobID == job.ID) && (job.ID == id)
    select img;
```

You can however use joins if you prefer the syntax. The DB side query execution plan will be exactly the same:

```
var tagsQry =
    from tag in db.Tags
    join jobTag in sb.JobTags on tag.ID equals jobTag.TagID
    where (jobTag.JobID == id)
    select tag;

var userImageQry =
    from appJob in db.AppliedJobs
    join img in db.Images on appJob.UserID equals img.UserID
    join job in db.Jobs on appJob.JobID equals job.ID
    where (job.ID == id)
    select img;
```

In the second example you only need the query (or join) to `Jobs` if you don't have a foreign key constraint on `AppliedJobs.JobID`. If you do, you can compare `AppliedJobs.JobID` directly with `id`.

Comment: Actually I complete forgot about navigation properties, but either way my dilemma was about `JOIN` and why should I use or not, because I see no point of it after a long time of learning MVC.